# Retrieving count of unique Django objects based on multiple fields of another Django model

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a Django model defined as follows:

```
class Session(models.Model):
    ...
    leader = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='leader')
    follower = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='follower')
    ...
```

Now let's say I have a QuerySet of `Session` objects:

```
some_sessions = Session.objects.filter(some_criteria=True)
```

How can I get a simple count of unique `User`s that have been either a `leader` or `follower` in any Session in `some_sessions`?

For example, a particular `User` may have been a `leader` in some number of `Session` objects, but a `follower` in a handful of other `Session` objects. That particular `User` should only contribute 1 to the desired unique `User`s count.

There are of course some naive solutions to this, but for performance reasons, I'm wondering if there's a solution that leverages the power of QuerySets a bit more, if possible.

EDIT: To clarify, here's a naive method that gives the result I need:

```
active_user_ids = set()
some_sessions = Session.objects.filter(some_criteria=True)
for session in some_sessions:
    active_user_ids.add(session.leader.id)
    active_user_ids.add(session.follower.id)
all_active_users = User.objects.filter(id__in=active_user_ids).count()
```

Comment: Try: User.leader_set.all().count() and User.follower_set.all().count()

Comment: @user6837382 thank you, but this would not get me the count that I want. For example, if users 1-100 are leaders and users 51-150 are followers, your method would result in a total count of 200, not the desired 150.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A smart way of doing this is querying `User` instead of `Session`. Read more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).

```py
from django.db.models import Q
# ... Other import here

users = User.objects.all(Q(leader__isnull=False) | Q(follower__isnull=False),).distinct()
```

This will give you any user where either related relations `leader/follower` is null.

If you want to add some filters based on `sessions` values, you could do something like:

```py
sessions = Session.objects.filter(**your_filters)
users = User.objects.all(
    Q(leader__in=sessions) | Q(follower__in=sessions),).distinct()
```

Comment: The problem here is that `leader` and `follower` are fields of `Session`, not `User`.

Comment: Using `related_name` will make your relations available within user instances
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name

Comment: Thank you! Finally, let's say that it's not `all_sessions = Session.objects.all()`, but instead `some_sessions = Session.objects.filter(some_criteria=True)`. (I plan to vary the `Session` queryset.) How can I get a count of unique Users that have been either a leader or follower in `some_sessions`?

Comment: Just added an example in response

Answer (score 0):

For get a simple count of unique User use `count` method.

```
active_user_ids = set()
all_sessions = Session.objects.all()
for session in all_sessions:
    active_user_ids.add(session.leader.id)
    active_user_ids.add(session.follower.id)
all_active_users = User.objects.filter(id__in=active_user_ids).count()
```

Comment: Thanks for seeing the typo. It so happens that I already did have that in my code; I just copy/pasted incorrectly. I have updated my question.